# Replace blank space by "-" inside excel field

Tags: excel, function, replace

I have value as below into columnA:

```
00259695 YYYYMMDD.CSV
004001 YYYYMMDD.CSV
004002 YYYYMMDD.CSV
0051TZTT YYYYMMDD.CSV
04002B YYYYMMDD.CSV
```

How to simply add "-" instaed of blank space between name and YYYYMMDD.csv?

To get like this:

```
00259695-YYYYMMDD.CSV
004001-YYYYMMDD.CSV
004002-YYYYMMDD.CSV
0051TZTT-YYYYMMDD.CSV
04002B-YYYYMMDD.CSV
```

Comment: Are you asking how to press ctrl+H or how to use the substitute function?

Comment: I try to replace but it did not working on my site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With data in column **A**, in **B1** enter:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","-")
```

and copy downwards:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Select the column where there's your date format

- CTRL+H
- Find : add the blank space
- Replace with : just the '-'
- And then replace all

You could easily find it with Google

Answer (score 0):

Use excels find and replace,

1. Copy the white space only,
2. Select only the range you wish to do this to.
3. CTRL+h
4. Expand on the options and un-tick match all cell
5. Enter in the replace section "-"
6. Done

Did you want a macro?